# Prove $(\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell_1^n)_{\ell_2}$ cannot admit a norm which is uniformly convex.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

Just as the title, prove $(\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell_1^n)_{\ell_2}$ cannot admit a norm which is uniformly convex.

I find in the answer of [A reflexive space which does not have an equivalent uniformly convex norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71151/a-reflexive-space-which-does-not-have-an-equivalent-uniformly-convex-norm/854296#854296)
, a user noticed using Enflo's theorem, but he did not mention what this theorem says, and I cannot find a version of this theorem on the internet.

Comment: A proof is in *Classical Banach Spaces II*, Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri, Lemma 1.e.4 and the remark preceeding it. See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=yPPrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q&f=false).