# Bidual of any NLS $X$ is $X$,i.e. $X^{**}=X$

Tags: normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

I am aware of isometric embedding of NLS(Normed Linear Space) $X$ into $X^{**}$. I am just curious to know whether there any classification or any other kind of beautiful theorem which says that they are isometrically isomorphic.

For $\mathbb{C}^{n**}\cong\mathbb{C}^n$. I know they are isometrically isomorphic.

Any kind of assumption on $X$ is fine like Hilbert, Normal or any other.

Comment: I assume NLS is an abbreviation for normed linear space?  You are describing what is known as a reflexive space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space  See the example section of the link for a number of conditions that guarantee reflexivity.  In particular, Hilbert spaces and $L^p$ spaces for $1<p<\infty$ are reflexive.  (of course, finite dimensional normed spaces are also always reflexive).

Comment: Thank you very much @MW :).

Comment: @MW. Maybe I think to remove this question from unanswered ones you can answer those which you have commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Upgrading from comment to answer as suggested.]

You are describing what is known as a [reflexive space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space). See the example section of the link for a number of conditions that guarantee reflexivity. Particularly important examples of reflexive spaces include [uniformly convex spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space), which include Hilbert spaces and $L^p$ spaces for $1<p<\infty$.  Finite dimensional normed spaces are also always reflexive, since the dual (and therefore also the bidual) has the same dimension as the original space.

##### Remark

Uniformly convex spaces (or those that have an equivalent uniformly convex norm) are not the only examples of reflexive spaces, as the result of M. M. Day cited in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71155/1210477) shows.